# How to determine the range of `a` in this inequation formula?

Tags: derivatives, inequality

$
a^x ≥ x +1, x∈R
$

What is the range of `x` such that this inequation is constantly true？

I tried to transform the inequation into the following：
$
xlna ≥ ln(x+1)
$, which can get the following inequation

$$\begin{cases}
\ lna ≥ \frac{ln(x+1)}{x}, x＞ 0\\
\ lna ≤ \frac{ln(x+1)}{x}, x < 0
\end{cases}$$

In two cases, it seems we cannot calculate the maximum value of the right-side equation, which in turn, determines the range of `a`.

The derivative to the right-side equation is

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}-{ln(x+1)}}{x^2}
\end{align}$$

It seems that we cannot figure out the extreme point

Comment: GPT: would you Differentiate between ’inequation’ and ‘inequity’ and ‘inequality’ when you are ready?

Comment: We have to assume $a>0$ to make sense of $a^x$ for all real $x$. And then the inequality in question is sufficient to prove that $a=e$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1776286/72031