# Intuition for $e^{ix}$ lies on the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition

I do know that for any $x$, the complex number $e^{ix}$ have to lie on the unit circle because if we plot the points for $\cos x + i\sin x$ for each $x$, we will eventually form a circle.

Are there any more intuitive approach on why $e^{ix}$ lies on the unit circle?

Comment: *More intuitive* than basic geometry and trigonometry??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding relation of $\sin,\cos,\tan$ with $e$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109537/understanding-relation-of-sin-cos-tan-with-e)

Comment: There is no intuition for (the LHS of) the Euler formula because this is an analytic result not linked to geometry directly or anything that can be visualized. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

Comment: $|e^{ix}| = 1$?

Comment: There are some videos that explain it nicely.  See [this one from 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU) or [this one from Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dhHrg-KbJ0).

Comment: @Masacroso just because the result isn't "directly linked to geometry" under its usual presentation/proof, doesn't mean that it can't be visualized.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I dont think so. The definition of $e^{ix}$ and it geometric interpretation becomes from the analytic series of trigonometric functions. The function $e^{ix}$ alone dont have any geometrical interpretation. The videos you linked hides all of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a perspective I like: consider the function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ given by $f(t) = e^{it}$, and note that we can think of $\Bbb C$ as a two dimensional space (that is, $\Bbb C$ is isometric $\Bbb R^2$).  Now, we note that if we apply the usual rules of calculus, we have
$$
\frac {df}{dt} = i\,e^{it}
$$
Now, let's split this function into its real and imaginary parts.  That is, say that
$$
f(t) = f_R(t) + i f_I(t)
$$
where $f_R(t),f_I(t) \in \Bbb R$.  Equivalently, we can think of $f(t) = (f_R(t),f_I(t))$ as tracing out a trajectory in $\Bbb R^2$.  Along these lines, we have
$$
f'(t) = if(t) = i[f_R(t) + i f_I(t)] = -f_I(t) + if_R(t)
$$
Equivalently, we see that when we follow the trajectory of $f(t)$, its tangent vector points in the direction of $(-f_I(t),f_R(t))$.

Note: we are **not** assuming Euler's formula, which would tell us that $f_R(t) = \cos(t)$ and $f_I(t) = \sin(t)$.

Now, we use a handy fact:

> For $\alpha: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$, we have
>   $$
> \frac{d}{dt}\|\alpha(t)\|^2 = \frac{d}{dt} \langle \alpha(t),\alpha(t) \rangle = 2 \langle \alpha'(t), \alpha(t) \rangle
> $$
>   where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the usual "dot product".

With that, we may now conclude that 
$$
\frac {d}{dt} |f(t)|^2 = \langle (f_R(t),f_I(t)), (-f_I(t),if_R(t)) \rangle = 0
$$
That is: *because $f'(t)$ points in a direction orthogonal to the position $f(t)$ (relative to the origin), the magnitude of $f(t)$ (i.e. its distance from the origin) remains constant*.

Now, since $|f(0)| = |e^0| = 1$, we can conclude that for any $t$, $|f(t)| = 1$.  That is, $f(t)$ traces a trajectory on the unit circle.  That is, for any $t$, $e^{it}$ is on the unit circle, which is what we wanted to show.

---

It is notable that from here, we may see that $|f'(t)| = \|\alpha'(t)\| = 1$, which tells us that the unit circle is traced one length unit per unit length in $t$, which is enough for us to deduce Euler's formula in its full form.

Comment: In my opinion this is the key intuition about $e^{ix}.$ An illustration of successive approximations of the trajectory can be found in [this answer to another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2109566) and in [a relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity).

Comment: You are using the fundamental property of exponential function which is $(e^{x})' = e^{x}$ which leads to $(e^{it})' = ie^{it}$. If this is known we can directly consider the function $g(t) = (\cos t - i\sin t)e^{it}$ and show that $g'(t) = 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's a neat approach! Gets you Euler's identity with no Taylor series required, actually. I don't know how much this does for intuition, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any 
intuition -
it just *is*.

Once $e^{ix}
= \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$
has been established
it is obvious,
but until then,
no.

In my opinion,
any of the answers here
that attempt to
produce an intuitive reason
require more advanced reasoning
than deriving
Euler's (or d'Alembert's)
formula.

Comment: am i right to say for any complex number $z$, $z$ can be represented by  $z = re^{ix}$, and since $r$ is the length of $z$, we have $z$ lying on the circle with radius $r$ centered at 0? So any complex number lies on a circle?

Comment: @ilovewt Yes you're correct. But the OP knows that and wants some intuitive idea about why it's true.

Comment: I don't think the use of advanced reasoning is incompatible with intuition. It just means it takes longer before you are able to develop the intuition. I'm reminded of all the integrals I had to solve with change of variables in first-year calculus, which seemed a dull mechanical exercise at the time but suddenly became illustrations of a beautiful idea about two years deeper into real analysis.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what you mean by the symbol $e^{ix}$ for all real $x$. One way to introduce this symbol is to use the definition $$e^{z} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^{n}, z\in\mathbb{C}\tag{1}$$ and in particular if $z = ix, x \in\mathbb{R}$ then $$f(x) = e^{ix} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{ix}{n}\right)^{n}\tag{2}$$ We can now prove easily that $|f(x)| = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It is in fact better to show equivalently that $|f(x)|^{2} = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This we do next.

Clearly $$|f(x)|^{2} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|1 + \frac{ix}{n}\right|^{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}\tag{3}$$ Now as $n \to \infty$ it is clear that after some value of $n$ we have $|x/n| < 1$ and hence by Bernoulli's inequality we have $$1 - n\cdot\frac{x^{4}}{n^{4}}\leq \left(1 - \frac{x^{4}}{n^{4}}\right)^{n} \leq 1$$ and hence by Squeeze theorem we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{x^{4}}{n^{4}}\right)^{n} = 1\tag{4}$$ Similarly we can show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{n} = 1\tag{5}$$ Dividing equation $(4)$ by equation $(5)$ we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{n} = 1$$ and thus by equation $(3)$ we conclude that $|f(x)|^{2} = 1$ for all real $x$. It follows that the complex number $f(x) = e^{ix}$ lies on the unit circle $|z| = 1$ for all real $x$.

Note further that the argument of $f(x)$ can be handled even more easily. Clearly we can see that $$\operatorname{arg}f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n\arctan(x/n) = x$$ and thus it is clear that $f(x) = e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1668179/72031) for another proof of $f(x) = \cos x + i\sin x$.

Comment: im actually just confused why $e^{ix}$ traces out a circle . Or lie on a circle. I can understand all the proofs of eulers formula, but failed to see how it lies on a unit circle

Comment: @ilovewt: Any complex number $z$ with $|z| = 1$ lies on unit circle. That is in fact the meaning of "lying on unit circle in complex plane". I have chosen a definition of symbol $e^{ix}$ and shown that $|e^{ix}| = 1$ and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just calculate it directly, using the power laws and the fact that $\overline{\mathrm e^z}=\mathrm e^{\overline z}$:
$$\left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}\right|^2
= \mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}\,\overline{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}}
= \mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ix}
= \mathrm e^{\mathrm ix-ix} = \mathrm e^0 = 1$$

On why $\overline{\mathrm e^z}=\mathrm e^{\overline z}$:

There are several definitions of $\mathrm e^x$, so the details differ, but the common theme is the same: $z$ is the only complex quantity in the definition.

1. The series definition:
   $$\mathrm e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
   Note that $k!$ is a real number for each $k$, $\overline{x+y}=\overline x+\overline y$ and $\overline{x\cdot y}=\overline x\cdot\overline y$. Since $z$ is the only complex quantity in the definition, the relation holds for the partial sums:
   $$\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\overline z^k}{k!}$$
   And since $\overline z$ is continuous, the same holds for the limit.
2. The limit definition
   $$\mathrm e^z = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n$$
   Again, $z$ is the only quantity that is not real, and for each $n$, the expression under the limit is constructed only from sums and products (note that $\frac{z}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot z$ where $\frac1n$ is real, and that $x^n=x\cdot x\cdots x$), therefore $$\overline{\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n}=\left(1+\frac{\overline z}{n}\right)^n.$$ And again, the same holds for the limit because $\overline z$ is continuous.

Comment: Is there any intuition as to why $e^{\bar{z}}=\bar{e^z}$?

Comment: @ASKASK: See my edit.