# Limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left(\cos\frac{x}{n} + \sin\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

> Given the limit:
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) +
> \sin\left(\frac{2x}{n}\right)\right]^{n} =
> \alpha
> $$
>
> Find the value of $\alpha$.
>
> ---

I suppose there is a special technique of how to solve such expressions. Sadly, I am not familiar with it.

Could anyone put me on point ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the following Taylor expansions at $0$, $\cos(t)=1+o(t)$, $\sin(t)=t+o(t)$, and $\ln(1+t)=t+o(t)$, we have that
$$\begin{align}\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) 
+ \sin\left(\frac{2x}{n}\right)\right)^n &=\exp\left(n \ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{2x}{n}\right)\right)\right)
\\&=\exp\left(n \ln\left(1 + \frac{2x}{n}+o(1/n)\right)\right)
\\&=\exp\left(n \left(\frac{2x}{n}+o(1/n)\right)\right).
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I initially wanted to solve it using the expansion.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

$$\cos\frac xn\approx1^*,\\\sin\frac{2x}n\approx\frac{2x}n^*$$ then

$$\left(1+\frac{2x}n\right)^n\to e^{2x}.$$

$^*$ the next terms are negligible.

Comment: Yves. +1.The devil is in the detail.

Comment: I think you meant e^2x

Comment: @Sopel: absolutely, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $$a_{n} =\frac{\cos(x/n) +\sin(2x/n)}{1+(2x/n)}$$ and then we have $$n(a_n-1)=n\cdot\frac{\cos(x/n) - 1+\sin(2x/n)-(2x/n)}{1+(2x/n)}$$ and it is easily seen that $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ and [therefore $a_n^{n} \to 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/72031). Using the fact that $(1+(2x/n))^{n}\to e^{2x}$ the desired limit is $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Why do we have a denominator in the sequence? How did we get it?

Comment: @E.Z.: I added it myself. The sequence $a_n$ is of the form $b_n/c_n$ where we need to evaluate limit of $b_n^n$ and the limit of $c_n^n$ is well known. We show that $a_n^n\to 1$ so that $b_n^n$ tends to same limit as that of $c_n^n$ which is well known.

Comment: Well, okay. I understand the logic but it is not obvious, however. At least, for me.

Comment: @E.Z : I expect that. This technique is not famous. But it is useful in dealing with such limits. For example you can use it to prove that $(1+(ix/n))^{n}\to\cos x+i\sin x$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Where to read more on that, specifically?

Comment: @E.Z.: well I learnt the technique on this website only and used it in some of my answers. You should see the link given in this answer. I will give a link to one of my answers in next comment.

Comment: @E.Z.: see this answer which uses this technique : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1668179/72031

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin(2a) =2\cos a\sin a $, $\sin x\sim x$  and $\cos x\sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\cos\frac{x}{n} + \sin\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1 + 2\sin\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\left(\cos\frac{x}{n} \right)^n \\ \sim \left(1 + \frac{2x}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}\right)^n \\\overset{\color{red}{h=\frac{x}{n}}}{=}\underbrace{\exp\left(2x\frac{\ln(1+2h)}{2h}\right)}_\overset{h\to 0}{\to e^{2x}}  \underbrace{\exp\left(\frac{xh}{2}\frac{\ln(1-\frac{h^2}{2})}{\frac{h^2}{2}}\right)}_{\overset{h\to 0}{\to 1} }\overset{h\to 0}{\to} e^{2x}$$

Given that $$ \lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+X)}{X} =0$$

Comment: Should $(1 - \frac{x^2}{2n^2})$ be with $n$, not a squared one?

Comment: @E.Z. we have this $\cos x\sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ right?

Comment: Right. $\cos\frac{x}{n} \sim 1 - \frac{x^2}{2n}$?

Comment: @E.Z. first let $h=\frac{x}{n}$ then $\cos h\sim 1-\frac{h^2}{2}$ then replace now

Comment: Oh. Okay. Sorry.