# Convergence of $(1-\frac{1}{kn})^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to examine the convergence of $(1-\frac{1}{kn})^n$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. My intuition is that for $k=1$, the sequence converges towards $1/e$ and for all other value for $k$, it should converge towards $0$. I'm just unsure about how to prove this.

Comment: It converges to $e^{-1/k}$. More generally, $\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n$ converges to $e^x$; there are many ways to prove this.

Comment: How can I show this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186210/how-to-show-lim-k-rightarrow-infty-left1-fraczk-rightk-ez?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668114/how-to-find-lim-n-to-infty-left-1-fraczn-rightn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the well known limit 
$$
(1+x/n)^n\to e^x
$$
for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Take $x=-1/k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{kn}\right)^n=\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{kn}\right)^{kn}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\to \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^k$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}^{} (1-\frac{1}{kn})^{n}_{}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}^{} e^{\log(1-\frac{1}{kn})^{n}_{}}=  e^{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}^{} \frac{\log(1-\frac{1}{kn})}{1/n}}= e^{ \lim_{n \rightarrow 0}^{} \frac{\log(1-\frac{n}{k})}{n}} \stackrel{\text{L'Hospital's rule}}{=} e^{-\frac{1}{k}}_{}$