# Sequences and series evaluating limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I know the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ tends to $e$, but how do I use this fact to find the limit of $(1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n^2})^n$ as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{z}{k}\right)^k=e^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186210/how-to-show-lim-k-rightarrow-infty-left1-fraczk-rightk-ez) The $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ term is negligble (take out a common factor).

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n^2})^n=e^{n\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n^2})}$

Comment: $\ln(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon^3-...$